# Post in MySql Database using RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I make a mobile app and I will use a web API to connect it with my database. I have a URL that I want to make a post request from it. The file that will get is an XML. For this request I use rest sharp From this XML I don't want all the information that has on it but the same information. Here is part of the XML file

```
<pricelist>
<priceentry>
    <station>2</station>
    <name>name</name>
    <address>
        <fulladdress>adreess</fulladdress>
        <zipcode>10442</zipcode>
        <dd>
            <code>A1010400</code>
            <dd_descr>adreess</dd_descr>
            <dimos_descr>state</dimos_descr>
            <nomos_descr>state1</nomos_descr>
        </dd>
    </address>
    <product>
        <code>12</code>
        <description>Shell   </description>
    </product>
    <price>1.568</price>
    <timestamp>1574432971030</timestamp>
    <company>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>SHELL</name>
    </company>
</priceentry>
<priceentry>
    <station>2</station>
    <name>name</name>
    <address>
        <fulladdress>adreess</fulladdress>
        <zipcode>10442</zipcode>
        <dd>
            <code>A1010400</code>
            <dd_descr>adreess</dd_descr>
            <dimos_descr>state</dimos_descr>
            <nomos_descr>state1</nomos_descr>
        </dd>
    </address>
    <product>
        <code>12</code>
        <description>Shell  95 V-Power</description>
    </product>
    <price>1.678</price>
    <timestamp>1574432985827</timestamp>
    <company>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>SHELL</name>
    </company>
</priceentry>
<priceentry>
    <station>2</station>
    <name>name</name>
    <address>
        <fulladdress>adreess</fulladdress>
        <zipcode>10442</zipcode>
        <dd>
            <code>A1010400</code>
            <dd_descr>adreess</dd_descr>
            <dimos_descr>state</dimos_descr>
            <nomos_descr>state1</nomos_descr>
        </dd>
    </address>
    <product>
        <code>13</code>
        <description>Shell  100 V-Power Racing</description>
    </product>
    <price>1.895</price>
    <timestamp>1574400586377</timestamp>
    <company>
        <code>2</code>
        <name>SHELL</name>
    </company>
</priceentry>
```

From this XML that I want is to take from each  only that ones that have product code 12. I have made this class for model

```
public class code
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String price { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String description { get; set; }
    public String lastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

and this in order to make a post request

```
      public void Post([FromBody]string value)
      {
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        string myConnnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();

        var client = new RestClient("http://www.fuelprices.gr/test/xml/get_prices.view");

        var request = new RestRequest("API/storage", Method.POST);
        request.AddParameter("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Length", "0");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.AddHeader("Host", "www.fuelprices.gr");
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PetraileoPersistence));
        PetraileoPersistence po = new PetraileoPersistence();
        request.AddParameter("code", "value");
        request.AddParameter("nomos_descr", "value2");
      }
```

but I have trouble to separate the necessary values in order to insert them in the database. So is there any tutorial in order to make that I want or any suggestion that will help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Deserialize the XML into a list using a process such as [this](http://www.janholinka.net/Blog/Article/11).
2. Iterate through the list looking for only those products with code 13, or use a Linq query to create a new List with just those products with code 13.

Answer (score 0):

Try following xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = "http://www.fuelprices.gr/test/xml/get_prices.view";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(URL);

            List<Code> codes = doc.Descendants("priceentry").Select(x => new Code()
            {
                id = (int)x.Element("product").Element("code"),
                price = decimal.Parse(((string)x.Element("price")).Replace(",","")),
                name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                description = (string)x.Element("product").Element("description"),
                lastUpdate = (string)x.Element("timestamp")
            }).ToList();

            Dictionary<int, List<Code>> dict = codes.GroupBy(x => x.id, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

        }
    }
    public class Code
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String description { get; set; }
        public String lastUpdate { get; set; }
    }
}
```